SwiftUI VideoPlayer in TabView with PageTabViewStyle controls not showing
In one of my projects I have a VideoPlayer() in a TabView with .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always)) to make a paginated carousel. The VideoPlayer has built-in controls for playing/pausing the video. For iOS16/iOS17 I needed to add .clipped() to make sure the controls were being displayed. (See this post). However, the controls are not visible on iOS18 with .tabViewStyle(.page))
when I remove the tabViewStyle modifier, the controls are showing again but I lose the horizontal scrolling behaviour.
Sample code to reproduce the issue:
        TabView {
            VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: URL(filePath: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4")!))
                .clipped()
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))

I tried wrapping the AVPlayerViewController in a UIViewControllerRepresentable but this resulted in the same issue.

AVPlayer is a class, you can't init object instances like that in body, only values or structs that have no lifetime.

I think this is yet another SwiftUI bug. I can reproduce your issue
in my tests, but found no workaround when using .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always)). Only works without it or using
.tabViewStyle(.automatic) or .tabViewStyle(.tabBarOnly)
